# What happens to a thread when it 'awaits' something

Tags: c#, async-await

When an `async` method `awaits` a `Task` what happens to the thread it's currently running on?

I surmise that on a UI thread the message loop resumes and on a thread pool thread the thread is released back to the thread pool. But what happens if the thread was started manually? Are there any other types of threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took me a long time to realize but this part of async-await is dead simple, just go up the call stack. Any time a method `awaits` something (assuming it's not a completed Task or anything similar) it returns to the caller. Since we're talking about the point where your code cedes control of the thread that means this is the last piece of your code on top of the stack.

If we're running on the UI thread we return back to the message loop. If we're on thread pool thread control returns to the thread pool. A manually created thread only runs a void method, you can only use `await` if it's an `async void` method which means it will end the thread at the first `await` even before the method has completed.

The continuations work the same way. It will queue it on either the UI thread or the thread pool, then it either `awaits` again or it finishes, ceding control once more.

Edit: I've done some experimenting with custom task schedulers and you can apply the exact same logic there. When the task awaits it cedes control. The task scheduler I used is based off this [single threaded task scheduler](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3063560/application-development/building-your-own-task-scheduler-in-c.html). In this case ceding control means the task scheduler starts working on the next task in the queue. It's also important to note that the continuations are scheduled with the current task scheduler unless `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used.

Comment: This is an incomplete and partially incorrect answer. Manual thread, thread pool thread or any thread can run any async method we want, it just needs to be wrapped into Task and then ran synchronously on the thread.

Comment: @ipvalu The question is what happens when a thread asynchronously awaits something. Synchronously waiting on a Task is something else entirely.

Comment: You say that manually created thread runs only async void method. Threads without any kind of synchronization context, scheduler. Such thread can run anything, even async task method. When you call any async method, it is like Task.RunSynchronously, it executes everything synchronously including awaits in it, as long as they are completed awaits and returns when all synchronous part in await is done or when it hits first not completed await(then rest runs on thread pool usually).

Comment: And there is no awaiting in your thread. You can not use await outside async method and as your thread has no synchronization context, scheduler, message pump, then you can not perform necessary actions to make it awaiting => running its continuations(code after not completed await call in async method, that will be completed later).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there is no such thing as a manual thread. They are all just threads. Like electrons, there are not two types of electrons:).

The difference between ThreadPool thread, your thread, UI thread, COM thread etc is if the thread has a message loop, synchronization context.
If the thread has synchronization context, then everything we start on it does not run directly, but it is all started as delegates from some queue and when there is nothing in the queue, the thread is waiting.

So if some part of your code in async method is running on such thread with synchronization context, then on await it stores the context, unless ConfigureAwait and is done with this method and is waiting for next delegate or message for execution. So when the await is done and ConfigureAwait was not used to move next code to thread pool, then it sends to synchronization context new delegate, which is code after await an it gets processed.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, any thread can run async method synchronously and it will wait until

=>

Stephen Cleary pointed out, that this part is not correct: "wait until the async method is done". The wording is really badly misleading. So perhaps this will be little better.

=>

all synchronously executed parts are done. Could be awaiting completed Task, like Task.FromResult. Also, it could be another async method, that could be executed completely synchronously.

But in a moment that await somewhere awaits operation that could not be completed before awaiter is provided, then the t.RunSynchronously will exit even when async method did not run to completion yet.

```
void ThreadWorker(object obj)
{
    var t = new Task<Task>(AsyncMethod);
    t.RunSynchronously();
    //in this case, it runs the AsyncMethod completely
    //and effectively waits for result
}

async Task AsyncMethod()
{
   await Something().ConfigureAwait(false);
   //everything from here runs on the ThreadPool
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. `RunSynchronously` waits until the task `t` is done; it does *not* wait until the task returned from `AsyncMethod` is done.

Comment: Well yes, but sometimes no, it all depends. I think, it would be correct if I would rather say, that it waits for all synchronously processed awaits in the async method, that includes awaiting completed tasks, which is not always known, but wont wait for async method completion in general.

Comment: The waiting part was not worded correctly as I wanted only to point out, that thread does not have to run only async void methods, but with the t.RunSynchronously async Task method can be invoked as well...

Comment: Oh, I realized that wrapping and synchronously running is doing the same thing as calling directly AsyncMethod(); in the ThreadWorker method, unless a scheduler would be explicitly required:)...

Comment: It looks like it's been corrected, but still doesn't answer the question IMO.

Comment: Nor does it upvoted answer: "A manually created thread only runs a void method". Incorrect...

Comment: Nor does it upvoted answer: "A manually created thread"  " can only use await if it's an async void". Also incorrect...

Comment: Nor does upvoted answer: " it will end the thread at the first await even before the method has completed." Technically not incorrect, but incomplete. Which my answer was pointing on...